# Is there a way to connect two open CMD windows; one for input commands, and the other to display the corresponding output?

Tags: input, cmd, windows-7, connection, output

The title of the question tells what I need to achieve. Is there a way to **connect two open CMD windows** so that I can input commands to one CMD window and display the corresponding output in the other CMD window.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to connect the windows directly.

You could have two batch files, one set to take user input and save it to a file, and another to loop through the file executing new entries.

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd` there are only two ways for communication between different processes: using a file and the (little known) `waitfor` command.
`waitfor` is a command (afaik the only one that works across command line windows) for signaling (see `waitfor /?` for details).

Sender.bat:

```
@echo off
:loop
set /p "command=command> "
%command% >output.txt 2>&1
waitfor /si NewData
goto :loop
```

Receiver.bat

```
@echo off
:loop
waitfor NewData 
type output.txt
del output.txt
goto :loop
```

The `waitfor /si` in `Sender.bat` sends a signal, when new data is available.
The `waitfor` in `Receiver.bat` waits until it receives the signal `NewData`, types the file to screen and deletes it.

Bonus: you can have `sender.bat` and `receiver.bat` on same or different computers (as long as they are in the same network; you should have the file on a common share then).